# Passing different values to threads in java networking?

Tags: java, multithreading, networking

I have a server and client code. In my server I am waiting for connection and creating two threads(only two clients for now). Here is a snippet of my server code.

```
while (true) {
            try {
                Socket client = server.accept();
                int i;
                for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
                    if(threads[i] == null) {
                        (threads[i] = new ClientThread(client, threads, i + 1)).start();
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if(i == 2) {
                    PrintStream os = new PrintStream(client.getOutputStream());
                    os.println("Server too busy. Try later.");
                    os.close();
                    client.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

In my ClientThread class, I have this constructor and run method.

```
public ClientThread(Socket sock, ClientThread[] threads, int count) {
            this.clientSocket = sock;
            this.threads = threads;
            this.count = count;
        } // end constructor

        public void run() {
            ClientThread[] threads = this.threads;

            try {
                is = new DataInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
                os = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
                os.writeUTF("Hello client"+count);
                System.out.println("Client sent =>"+ is.readUTF());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
                if (threads[i] == this) {
                  threads[i] = null;
                }
              }

            try {
                is.close();
                os.close();
                clientSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } // end run method
```

I am running a server and when a client gets connected, the client receives some string(along with count), this is printed out. Now another client should also connect and get an incremented count. But when I run my code, the server starts, and even if I run two clients, I still get only 1 as the output corresponding to count instead of it being as 1 for the first client and 2 for the second client.
Where am I going wrong?

Edit:
My Client is a simple socket code, which reads utf and writes utf. That's it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your program is right. Just try to figure out why the output is like this.

Think about this situation, **Before** the sever accepts the data sent by the **second** client:

```
Socket client = server.accept();
```

The thread for the first client(let's assume it as thread[0] according to your code) has finished its work, which means you assign `null` to thread[0]:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
     if (threads[i] == this) {
         threads[i] = null;
     }
 }
```

After this is done the server tries to accept the data sent by the second client so in the loop:

```
for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    if(threads[i] == null) {
        (threads[i] = new ClientThread(client, threads, i + 1)).start();
        break;
    }
}
```

the `thread[0]` is still `null` and the `count` is still 1 and you will still get the `1` as the output.

Suggestion:
If you want multiple threads working at the same time you can change your code:

```
...
is = new DataInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
os = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
os.writeUTF("Hello client"+count);
System.out.println("Client sent =>"+ is.readUTF());
TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(100);// Add this line to simulate working
...
```